# implement trait for same type with different bound

Tags: rust

I want to implement something like this

```rust
pub trait SomeTrait {
    fn return_vec() -> Vec<usize>;
}

impl<T, const N: usize> SomeTrait for [T; N] {
    fn return_vec() -> Vec<usize> {
        vec![N]
    }
}

impl<T: SomeTrait, const N: usize> SomeTrait for [T; N] {
    fn return_vec() -> Vec<usize> {
        let mut ret = vec![N];
        ret.append(&mut T::return_vec());
        ret
    }
}
```

And I get compiler error as below

```
conflicting implementations of trait `SomeTrait` for type `[_; _]`
conflicting implementation for `[_; _]`
```

The question is how can I implement trait for the same type but with different type bounds.

Comment: It's not possible [`specialization` or its smaller cousin `min_specialization`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31844) don't work in your case and [negative trait bounds](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/42721) aren't a thing either.

Comment: @cafce25 Yes, all I need is something like specialization of c++ template

Comment: @cafce25 [`specialization` does work](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=33cc8e657da50feb4e3ad87b89ef0e1d), but you should not use it.

Comment: @cafce25 why? because it is unstable?

Comment: Because it is unsound.